# What does “led by the US pressed [X]” mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Below is the headline of a newspaper

> The international community led by the US pressed Pakistan to deny safe haven to terror groups operating from its soil and bring the perpetrators of the Pulwama attack to justice.

Can someone please explain what the headline above means? What does `led by the US pressed Pakistan` mean?

Comment: The sentence reduces to: The community pressed (urged) Pakistan to deny.

Comment: Perhaps punctuation would help:  The international community, led by the US, pressed Pakistan to ...

Comment: @TRomano I agree, I would make "led by the US" parenthetical by the use of commas. However it is possible to argue that "The international community led by the US" is a long noun phrase which does not need commas. It's not a good argument because it implies tha there is more than one international community, one of which is led by the US. The parenthetical commas remove this implication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The international community **led by the US pressed Pakistan** to deny
>   safe haven to terror groups operating from its soil and bring the
>   perpetrators of the Pulwama attack to justice.

This is saying that the international community "pressed" Pakistan to take certain actions, and the USA *took the lead* or was the most significant country in doing the "pressing".

In this context, "press" means "exert (political) pressure". "Press" would normally apply to things like coordinated diplomatic entreaties, whereas overt threats such as the risk of trade sanctions (or other retaliation for non-compliance) would generally require a stronger word than "press".

> **[press](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/press)**
>   *transitive verb*
>
> 4a : to exert influence on : CONSTRAIN
>   4b : to try hard to persuade : BESEECH, ENTREAT
>
> 6a : to lay stress or emphasis on.
>   6b : to insist on or request urgently
>
> [source: Merriam-Webster Dictionary]

Comment: I am extremely Sorry I didn't mean to disappoint you and you have helped me a lot and you have also putted a lot of effort to make me understand. But why I have accepted his answer is He corrected me on how to read by just mentioning You have split the wrong part of the headline. (The international community led by the US) (pressed Pakistan). And Now I have accepted your answer because you made understand the word press in this particular context. Thank you and you both helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You have split the wrong part of the headline. (The international community led by the US) (pressed Pakistan). The US led the international community in pressing Pakistan. Here 'pressing' means 'trying hard to persuade'.

Comment: Here pressing Pakistan means Pressurising Pakistan Am I correct??